# Running an R script with parameters from python code

Tags: python, r, subprocess, rpy2

I have a very simple R scripts.

I need to give it 5 arguments from my python code, run it, and take a variable back to python.

So it should look like:

**R**

```
a<- a * b
r<- a + 3
```

**Python**

```
a = 3
b = 2

r = my_r_code
print(r)
>>> r = 9
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Check the `reticulate` package in R.

Comment: @meriops I need to run R from python , not python from R

Comment: Then [rpy2](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2) might be worth a look, but I never used it.